# mysql trigger for loop

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to do some mysql trigger coding. I fail every time I meet loops.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `table_users`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_user_plan (user_id, plan_id) VALUES 
    (NEW.id, (SELECT id FROM table_plans))
    ;
END
```

Here trigger is successfully created, but I get error

> #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

I understand this cannot work, because there are more than one row in table_plans... but how can I handle this if I want to add multiple rows or how can I make a loop and firstly select plans then insert into table_users?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Show the full code for your trigger. Also, MySQL is not SQL Server!

Answer (score 1):

To insert multiple rows based on a `SELECT` you would use the `INSERT ... SELECT FROM ...` syntax. In this case, you would use something like

```
INSERT INTO table_user_plan
  SELECT NEW.id AS user_id, tp.id AS plan_id
    FROM table_plans tp;
```

(I think that should work, although I've never actually tried to use `NEW` in this context.)

Comment: Even if it does not work, you can assign it to a variable and use it inside **select**. `SET @userId := NEW.id`